# ANDROID STUDIO: "The SOAP endpoint http://serverip:8080/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted. HTTP status: 404"

Tags: android, android-studio, soap, tfs

I'm trying to connect Android Studio to my TFS.

I've downloaded the `Visual Studio Team Services` plugin and followed this procedure:

Open Android Studio => "Check out project from Version Control" => TFS => choose my server => Insert username and psw

After this a message box says:

> The SOAP endpoint http: //serverip:8080/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 404

Android Studio version: 2.2.3

Team Foundation Server 2013

Anyone knows what's my problem? :s

Comment: Which version control are you using GIT or TFVC? And what's the detail version of your plug-in?

Comment: I'm using TFVC becouse i also use Visual Studio with TF and i've downloaded the plugin directly by android studio so i've the version 0.3.0.302

Comment: please see my update answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using TFVC and need TFS Plugin for Android Studio, you have to use this one- [Visual Studio Team Services Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio](http://java.visualstudio.com/Downloads/intellijplugin/Index)

*- Source Link: [TFVC Support in Preview for Team Services Plugin for
IntelliJ and Android Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/09/18/tfvc-support-in-preview-for-team-services-plugin-for-intellij-and-android-studio/#comment-180195)*

**Do not** use this tool-- [Team Foundation Server - Version Control Integration
for Android Studio](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio/plugin/7961-team-foundation-server--version-control-integration)

---

Unfortunately, this plugin only **supports authenticating VSTS or TFS2015** and above.
[image]

So, you have to either use VSTS or udpate your TFS sever version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if I've TFS2013 I can't use it?

Comment: p.s. I can't find that plugin.. do I need something special?

Comment: Yes for TFVC,you can't use it. To find that plugin ,detail steps please refer http://java.visualstudio.com/Downloads/intellijplugin/Index